# Coerce Class in R

Tags: r

With the md5-statement, I have created a code.
The statement `class(code)` returns: `[1] "hash" "md5"`. And when I try to use this in an 'if-else-then' statement, R produces a warning:  1:

```
    In if (class(code) == "character") { :  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
```

I tried to coerce code to have class "hash" only with

```
code <- as(code, Class = "hash")
```

but class(code) still returns [1] "hash" "md5".

How can I test for the class without having a warning?

Ben

Comment: Please show the problematic `if-then-else`

Comment: `if (inherits(code, "character"))`...

Comment: either `class(code) <- 'hash'` or `if ('character' %in% class(code))`

Comment: if (class(code) == "character") {
                  private$send0term_string(code)
                } else if (class(code)[1] == "hash") { 
                  private$send0term_string(code)
                } else { 
                  print("Unknown class")
                  print(class(code))
                  stop
                }

Comment: class(code <- "hash" worked. Thanx